# Is depth handled differently by opengl on different android phones?

Tags: android, opengl-es, depth

Im testing my new game prior to release and i have found that on some devices the Z positions seemed to be mixed up in some cases and objects that should appear on top were appearing underneath.

I'm running opengl es 1 and it runs perfectly on my Samsung Galaxy S2 (and all the samsung devices i tested on) but went wrong on a HTC Desire.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide us with some pictures and source code? Common depth buffer problems cause some banding problems but your problem seems more related to some default driver state that is set differently value depending on which hardware are you running on.

I suggest you to generate a very simple example and start from the scratch until you find where is the problem, I don't think we can help you with so little information.

Hope that helps.